# EMF Compare - How to ignore identifiers

Tags: eclipse, emf, ecore, emf-compare

I have 2 models to compare. In my *.ecore model, I have an "Id" attribute and its ID property have been setted to **true**. I am using EcoreUtil.generateUUID() for unique ids.

In my case, I have one ready model and I am creating a new one in runtime. Therefore the ids are different from each other.

In developer guide of EMFCompare, they offer us to use ***UseIdentifiers.NEVER***;

```
IEObjectMatcher matcher = DefaultMatchEngine.createDefaultEObjectMatcher(UseIdentifiers.NEVER);
```

Still, it produces mathces per node which have id like below:

> Left object: DocModel.impl.ParagraphImpl@2767e23c (Id: _8pidAdVSEeSCK78kxjXrDg) (name: null) (rawText: Lorem ipsum ....)
>
> Right object: DocModel.impl.ParagraphImpl@33bc72d1 (Id: _QSFJodrUEeSkqsl19NdwQQ) (name: null) (rawText: Lorem ipsum ....)
>
> d.getKind(): CHANGE

I guess comparison sees them CHANGE bacause of different ids.

In short, I want to ignore Id attributes in comparison.

thanks and regards

Comment: If you do not use the ID for comparison, then what is it for anyway?

Comment: You are right at one point about the reason of IDs usege. However, EMF Compare allows us to ignore IDs. I want to compare whole model except id fields.

Answer (score 1):

Before give you an answer, i want to fall into theory.

Emf compare uses two different ways of matching object. The first is **Id functions**, and another one is about **calculation distance** between objects in one group. By default, emf compare uses hybrid approach. If **id function** for element is available, than it will be invoked, otherwise it will match objects by nearest neighbour using distance functions. So, when you create matcher, you should specify strategy. In your case, you chose never to use id functions.

```
DefaultMatchEngine.createDefaultEObjectMatcher(UseIdentifiers.NEVER);
```

Actual comparison occurs not in match engine, but in **diff engine**.
All you need is just extend **DefaultDiffEngine** and override **createFeatureFilter** method to provider you own **FeatureFilter** .